# Swift 5.5: UISlider disable/enable animation inside custom TableView cell not working

Tags: swift, uitableview, tableview, uislider

I have created a custom UITableviewCell implementation using a XIB file and have added a UISlider inside of it that I want to be disabled when the cells load the first time, and be enabled when I click a button from the  table cell.
I set the "isEnabled" property of the Slider to be True with the button action.

When the tableView loads up the first time, the slider is disabled as intended, then I click the button, the property isEnabled is set to True but the Slider does not change its appeareance, it still looks greyed out until i click on it.

I have seen suggestions to use reloadTable() but in my case this is not acceptable. Is there something else that I can use to "bring back to life" the UISlider? Some function that refreshes only the UISlider not the entire table?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to figure it out with some help.
I was considering the cell as a data storage which is wrong and was trying to save information in the cells class directly. Instead of this I was taught to consider the cells as display storage so now I use a TableCell struct in which I store the configuration of each cell and then I use the function `cellForRowAt` to update the cell each time with this information.
In my specific case I was using `reloadRows(at:with:)` to reload the cell but I was not setting it up. Btw, when calling `reloadRows(at:with:)` you actually call the `cellForRowAt` too.

```
struct TableCellData {
//Whatever data you may have in your cell and needs an update when it's displayed goes here
var sliderOn: Bool = false
....
}
```

Custom Cell class and its protocol. I was using a UISegmentedControl with three values and for its first value I was disabling the UISlider

```
protocol CellDelegate{
    func didUpdateSegment(at index:IndexPath, sliderOn: Bool)
}

class Cell: UITableViewCell {
var delegate: CellDelegate?
var cellIndexPath: IndexPath?

@IBOutlet weak var cellSlider: UISlider!

@IBAction func segmentPressed(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
    var sliderOn: Bool = false
    switch segment.selectedSegmentIndex {
    case 0:
        sliderOn = false
    case 1:
        sliderOn = true
    case 2:
        sliderOn = true
    default:
        sliderOn = false
    }
    if let safeCellIndexPath = cellIndexPath {
        self.delegate?.didUpdateSegment(at: safeCellIndexPath, sliderOn: sliderOn)
    }
}

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
    segment.selectedSegmentIndex = 0
}
```

In your ViewController you should have your cellData array which you should initialize in viewDidLoad() or somewhere else with the exact number of table cell rows. I will not include this part here but it should be something like `cellData = Array(repeating: TableCellData(), count: nbOfTableItems)`

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    ....
    var cellData : [TableCellData] = []
    ....
}
```

Then in your CellDelegate extension:

```
extension ViewController: CellDelegate {
   func didUpdateSegment(at index: IndexPath, sliderOn: Bool)  {
      cellData[index.row].sliderOn = sliderOn
      myTableView.reloadRows(at: [index], with: .none)
}
```

In cellForRowAt func:

```
extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "myCellName", for: indexPath) as! Cell
        
        cell.delegate = self
        cell.cellIndexPath = indexPath
        //isEnabled property did not work for me so I use the following to enabled/disable the UISLider of a cell
        cell.cellSlider.isUserInteractionEnabled = cellData[indexPath.row].sliderOn
        cell.cellSlider.alpha = cellData[indexPath.row].sliderOn == true ? 1.0 : 0.5
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative for reloading the whole `tableView` by calling `reloadTable()` would be just reloading the affected rows by using `reloadRows(at:with:)` ([docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614935-reloadrows)). Perhaps this is acceptable in your case?